# I can't add a user to the wheel group

Tags: linux, ubuntu

When i try to add a user in the wheel group:

```
usermod -g wheel gex
```

I get this error:

```
usermod: group 'wheel' does not exist
```

Answer (score 9):

The error message is quite obvious: the 'wheel' group does not exist. It's typically a groupname used on BSD systems, not on Linux. On Ubuntu, it does not exist by default and will need to be created: `addgroup wheel`. However, it's probably best if you edit your question and tell us what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 5):

As Teun Vink says, the `wheel` group does not exist by name in Ubuntu.  This may help solve the problem the Ubuntu way: [Wheel Group: Updated](http://administratosphere.wordpress.com/2011/07/22/the-wheel-group-updated/).

Additionally (and/or for Linux distros with a `wheel` group), the correct syntax for what you are trying to do is:

```
usermod -a -G wheel gex
```

Note the capital 'G'.

Using the `-a` option appends the new group, so the user doesn't lose their previous groups.

Using the lowercase `-g` option puts the user in that group as his/her primary group.

Using the upper case `-G` option adds the user to supplemental groups:
[`man usermod`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/usermod).

Answer (score 0):

Install the sudo package

#> apt install sudo

This seems to add the wheel group by default